# Проверка части нескольких массивов чисел на наличие чисел от 1 до 9

Tags: javascript, массивы

Дана матрица из целых чисел от 1 до 9, размером 3 * N, где N может быть
больше либо равна 3. Необходимо определить содержит ли каждый участок
матрицы 3 * 3 все числа от 1 до 9.

```js
let array = [
    [1, 2, 3, 2, 7],
    [4, 5, 6, 8, 1],
    [7, 8, 9, 4, 5]
];
```

Подскажите как это можно сделать

Comment: И с чем возникли сложности?

Comment: Закрывающие, как "необходимо конкретизировать", что тут можно конкретизировать? По-моему, конкретнее сформулировать тут уже особо и не куда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так.

- Получаем индекс начала последней группы.
- Проходимся в цикле от `0` до этого индекса.
- В каждой итерации создаём из полной матрицы её участок из трёх элементов каждого ряда, а потом превращаем этот участок в линейный массив. Обе операции можно сделать сразу при помощи [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).
- После того, как мы получили массив из `9` цифр, можно схитрить —  превратить этот массив в `Set`. Если количество элементов `Set` всё ещё будет равным `9`, значит все цифры были разные и участок проходит проверку.
- Если встретили хоть один неправильный участок, сразу возвращаем `false`. Иначе возвращаем `true` после цикла.

```js
const array = [
    [1, 2, 3, 2, 7],
    [4, 5, 6, 8, 1],
    [7, 8, 9, 4, 5]
];

function checkMatrix(matrix) {
  const latGroupStart = matrix[0].length - 3;

  for (let i = 0; i <= latGroupStart; i++) {
    const section = matrix.flatMap(row => row.slice(i, i + 3));
    const uniqueDigits = new Set(section);
    if(uniqueDigits.size < 9) return false;
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(checkMatrix(array));
```

Comment: Можно еще оптимизировать - после проверки изначального куска 3*3, дальше достаточно при смещении "окна", просто проверять совпадают ли три числа в уходящем столбце с тремя числами в появляющемся. И если нет, то возвращать false.